# @html and @tag On Mono (.NET)

Tags: c#, .net, razor, mono

I currently have Mono 3.12.1 installed along with MonoDevelop 5.7. I'm trying to build an application using Razor as my view engine. So far so good, the point is: When i try to use @html or @url tags, it doesn't work, it looks like it's not implemented in mono. So my final question is: Is there a way to achieve the code below with Mono 3.12.1?
@Html.ActionLink("Action","Controller") or @Url.Content("~/css/app.css")

Am i missing any dll??

Thanks in advance.